# Prove that the dual of the norm approximation problem has the given form.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the norm approximation:
$$
 (P) \begin{cases}
  \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \Vert Ax - b \Vert
  \end{cases}
$$

where $A \in \mathcal{M}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

---

**Part (1)**  — Write $(P)$ with an equality constraint.

***Attempt*:**

Since $\Vert Ax -b\Vert \geq 0$ then add the following constraint:
$$
(P) \begin{cases}
  \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \Vert Ax - b \Vert,\\
  \text{s.t.} \;\; Ax-b=0
  \end{cases}
$$
I am not sure if this is correct, or why this could be correct. It was pure intuition because the smallest value the norm can attain is $0$.

---

**Part (2)**  — Prove that the dual of $(P)$ is the following:
    $$
  (P^*) \begin{cases}
  \max_{\nu} \; \langle b, \nu \rangle, \\
  \text{s.t. } \; A^\top \nu = 0, \;\; \Vert \nu \Vert_* \leq 1.
  \end{cases}
 $$
The dual norm is defined as $\Vert \nu \Vert_* = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert \leq 1} \langle \nu, x\rangle $.

***Attempt*:**

The Lagrangian is $L(x,\nu) = \Vert Ax -b\Vert + \langle \nu,Ax-b \rangle$

I know that the Lagrangian dual problem is defined as:
$$
(P^*) \begin{cases}
  \max_{(\lambda,\nu)} \; \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R^n}} L(x,\lambda,
\nu)\\
  \text{s.t. } \; \lambda \geq 0
  \end{cases}
$$
Where $\lambda$ are the multipliers of the inequality constraints.

But I do not have any inequality constraints.

Can the $Ax - b = 0$ constraint be counted as $Ax - b \geq 0$ and $Ax - b \leq 0$?

---

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am really unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: I think what they mean in part 1 is to reformulate the problem as $\min\|u\|$ subject to $u=Ax-b$, and proceed with part 2 from there. What you did is pulling  a most likely infeasible constraint out of the blue.